# ShareKit - share on Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sharekit

I am using ShareKit to share a simple text on Facebook. I use cocoapods to install ShareKit on my application (with iOS7, and XCode5), and follow the configuration tutorial [ConfigurationShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Configuration).
More specifically, I do the following things:

1) Write the URL Scheme into the plist.

2) Create a DefaultSHKConfigurator sub-class:

```
@interface MySHKConfigurator : DefaultSHKConfigurator

@end

@implementation MySHKConfigurator
- (NSString*)facebookAppId
{
    return @"xxx";
}
-(NSString *)appName
{
    return @"MyAppName";
}
- (NSArray*)facebookWritePermissions
{
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream", nil]; //@"offline_access",
}
- (NSArray*)facebookReadPermissions
{
    return nil; // this is the defaul value for the SDK and will afford basic read permissions
}
@end
```

3) Make the initial configuration in the AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.    
    DefaultSHKConfigurator *configurator = [[MySHKConfigurator alloc] init];
    [SHKConfiguration sharedInstanceWithConfigurator:configurator];
    //[SHK flushOfflineQueue];    
    return YES;
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [SHKFacebook handleDidBecomeActive];
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Save data if appropriate
    [SHKFacebook handleWillTerminate];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
    NSString* scheme = [url scheme];    

    if ([scheme hasPrefix:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb%@", SHKCONFIG(facebookAppId)]]) {
        return [SHKFacebook handleOpenURL:url];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

4) Share on Facebook

```
- (IBAction)shareFacebook:(id)sender {            
    //- The url should be a link to your app on the app store
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    //- Share on Facebook
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:self.textView.text contentType:SHKURLContentTypeWebpage];
    [SHKFacebook shareItem:item];    
}
```

Now, What result I got on the real device is a facebook confirm dialog with question: "You have already authorized MyApp". After I push OK button, it comes back to the share dialog. And after I push the "Send To Facebook", it once again comes back to the Facebook confirm dialog with the above question. This cycle loops forever.

Do you know what did I miss? Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using accounts framework?

Comment: What do you mean by accounts framework? Can you tell me more in details? I only know that the ShareKit is the best library to share on multiple social networks. No?

Comment: I did spend some time on ShareKit, so I do not want to switch to another. Because I do not know that with the Accounts Framework, I do not get the same error.

Comment: You may want to look at UIActivityViewController as well, personally not a fan of share kit.

Comment: It seems that for whatever reason ShareKit is using SHKFacebook, instead of modern SHKiOSFacebook (which should use Accounts.framework). SHKFacebook is historically not perfect, and by accident I am rewriting it at the moment, and I have encountered that cycling bug too. Should be fixed soon. However, you should preferably use SHKiOSFacebook sharer. Do you have custom Sharers.plist? This might be the cause ShareKit fails back to old SHKFacebook sharer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh I see now - if you prefer to call sharer directly, than call

```
[SHKiOSFacebook shareItem:item];
```

The difference between SHKFacebook and SHKiOSFacebook is that the former uses Facebook iOS SDK, while the latter uses Accounts.framework and Social.framework.

Comment: I already fixed this issue by using SHKiOSFacebook. However, using SHKiOSFacebook, we cannot catch the events of SHKSharerDelegate protocol, like when start sending, finish sending, etc.

Comment: Another thing is I use SHKGooglePlus to share a text [SHKGooglePlus shareItem:item]. By storing text in SHKItem, the text is not included in the textview of GooglePlus dialog. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you explain more about SHKSharerDelegate protocol? Have you supplied your own delegate? Maybe notifications would be better? What do you need delegate for?

Comment: I think SHKSharerDelegate protocol allows us to know when the sharing is finished successfully or failed with specific error. NO???

Comment: Yes, but if you do not supply your own delegate via configuration, the default one just shows activity indicators. ShareKit's notifications are better suited for this purpose. They are defined in SHK.h. However, I am curious how SHKSharerDelegate did not work? Can you describe it more, where you supplied the delegate?